# How to use Office-ui-fabric Brand Icons

Tags: ms-office, office-ui-fabric

I am working on a Microsoft product in which I want to use **Microsoft Teams** Icon. 
Office UI fabric provides icons of Microsoft Products. But it does not provide a proper way to use them in an app.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/styles/web/office-brand-icons

The document states that you can use the brand icons through **Icon** component, but does not provide sample code for the same.

[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htOb1.png)

Is there any proper way to use these icons?
Can we really use them using **Icon** component?

We can use it by importing the styles separately but I don't think its the proper way.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/6.0.0/css/fabric.min.css">

<div class="ms-Fabric">
    <h1 class="ms-font-su">Branded Icon Test</h1>
    <div class="ms-BrandIcon--icon96 ms-BrandIcon--xlsx"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check the above code on https://codepen.io/jahnp/pen/ZeZBpg